# Find out the number of days of a month in R

Tags: r, date

I have a date in P

```
 date = as.Date("2011-02-23", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Is it possible to find out the number of days of the month of that particular date? (With respect to leapyears). In PHP it would look similar to this (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
days = format(date, "%t")
```

but "%t" seems to have a different meaning in R. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can write simple function to do that:

```
numberOfDays <- function(date) {
    m <- format(date, format="%m")

    while (format(date, format="%m") == m) {
        date <- date + 1
    }

    return(as.integer(format(date - 1, format="%d")))
}
```

Invoke as:

```
> date = as.Date("2011-02-23", "%Y-%m-%d")
> numberOfDays(date)
[1] 28
> date # date is unchanged
[1] "2011-02-23"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works if the date passed is the first of the month.

Comment: Doesn't work for vectors...check out my method below

Answer (score 48):

`lubridate` package has required function "days_in_month" with respect to leapyears.

Your example:

```
    date <- as.Date("2011-02-23", "%Y-%m-%d")
    lubridate::days_in_month(date)
    # Feb
    # 28
```

Leap year (2016):

```
    date_leap <- as.Date("2016-02-23", "%Y-%m-%d")
    lubridate::days_in_month(date_leap)
    # Feb 
    # 29
```

Answer (score 37):

The [Hmisc library](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Hmisc/html/yearDays.html) has a couple of helpful functions for doing this:

```
require(Hmisc)
monthDays(as.Date('2010-01-01'))
```

Answer (score 20):

That is as easy as taking a difference between two dates -- so make it the first of the month and the following month:

```
R> difftime( as.Date("2011-06-01"), as.Date("2011-05-01") )
Time difference of 31 days
R> as.numeric(difftime( as.Date("2011-06-01"), as.Date("2011-05-01") ))
[1] 31
R>
```

The `as.numeric()` casts this to a number you can use.

Answer (score 14):

Here are a couple of approaches.  Both approaches are vectorized, i.e. the input `x` can be a single `"Date"` class date or a vector of such dates.

**1)** This converts the input date, `x`, into a `"yearmon"` object and then converts it back to the last of the month and first of the month and subtracts the two adding 1.

```
x <- Sys.Date() # use today as the test date

library(zoo)
ym <- as.yearmon(x)
as.Date(ym, frac = 1) - as.Date(ym) + 1
## Time difference of 30 days
```

or for a numeric result use:

```
as.numeric(as.Date(ym, frac = 1) - as.Date(ym) + 1)
## [1] 30
```

**1a)** A variation would be:

```
as.Date(ym + 1/12) - as.Date(ym)
## Time difference of 30 days
```

or for a numeric result:

```
as.numeric(as.Date(ym + 1/12) - as.Date(ym))
## [1] 30
```

**2)** This is a base solution.  First we define `fom` which inputs a `"Date"` vector and returns the first of the month of each component.  Now we just take the difference between the first of the next month and the first of the current month.

```
fom <- function(x) as.Date(cut(x, "month"))
fom1 <- fom(x)
fom2 <- fom(fom1 +  32)
as.numeric(fom2 - fom1)
## [1] 30
```

Comment: +1 I did not know about the `frac` arg of `as.Date()` -- where is this documented? It doesn't show up when I do `?as.Date`.

Comment: @Prasad, Try this: `library(zoo); ?as.Date.yearmon` .

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple way: for `n` in `28:31`, find the biggest number that results in a valid date. In my tests this is at least 4 times faster than any of the time-difference-based methods:

```
ndays <- function(d) {
  last_days <- 28:31
  rev(last_days[which(!is.na( 
                             as.Date( paste( substr(d, 1, 8), 
                                             last_days, sep = ''), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d')))])[1]
}

> ndays('1999-03-10')
[1] 31
> ndays('1999-04-10')
[1] 30
> ndays('2000-02-10')
[1] 29
```

Timing comparisons with some of the other methods suggested here:

```
> system.time( replicate( 5000, 
                          nd <- { 
   ym <- as.yearmon('2011-06-01'); 
   as.numeric( as.Date(ym, frac = 1) - as.Date(ym) + 1)
   }))

   user  system elapsed 
 16.634   1.807  18.238 

> system.time( replicate( 5000, 
               nd <- as.numeric( difftime( as.Date("2011-06-01"), 
                                           as.Date("2011-05-01") ))))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.137   0.341   3.470 

> system.time( replicate( 5000, nd <- ndays('2011-06-01')))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.729   0.044   0.771
```

Comment: If one only does this on a single date as in the example above it would not matter what the speed is whereas if one is doing it on many dates then the `yearmon` approach is faster since its already vectorized.  Try timing `d <- Sys.Date() + 1:100; sapply(d, ndays)` vs. `d <- Sys.Date() + 1:100; ym <- as.yearmon(d); as.numeric(as.Date(ym, frac = 1) - as.Date(ym) + 1)`  On my system the latter is 5x faster.  That said, the speed is typically unimportant in any case.  The simplicity of the `yearmon` solution seems the more important advantage.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Very good point, I compared the times, and I agree with you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another possible function that doesn't require any packages to be installed. You just feed the function a date object. Since there's lots of other excellent answers here I wrote it with an eye towards being fairly straightforward and (hopefully) easy to read :)

```
daysInMonth <- function(d = Sys.Date()){

  m = substr((as.character(d)), 6, 7)              # month number as string
  y = as.numeric(substr((as.character(d)), 1, 4))  # year number as numeric

  # Quick check for leap year
  leap = 0
  if ((y %% 4 == 0 & y %% 100 != 0) | y %% 400 == 0)
    leap = 1

  # Return the number of days in the month
  return(switch(m,
                '01' = 31,
                '02' = 28 + leap,  # adds 1 if leap year
                '03' = 31,
                '04' = 30,
                '05' = 31,
                '06' = 30,
                '07' = 31,
                '08' = 31,
                '09' = 30,
                '10' = 31,
                '11' = 30,
                '12' = 31))
}
```

Comment: If you make your leap check `y %% 4 == 0 & (y %% 100 != 0 | y %% 400 == 0)` then it will always work.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically Dirk's approach but actually placed in a function, in order to check when the next month is also in the next year; and simply subtracting the dates is the same as using `difftime()`:

```
numberOfDays <- function(d){
    temp <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(d),"-"))
    begin <- as.Date(paste(temp[1],temp[2],"01",sep="-"))
    if (temp[2] != "12"){
        nextMonth <- as.character(as.integer(temp[2])+1)
        end <- as.Date(paste(temp[1],nextMonth,"01",sep="-"))
        return(as.integer(as.Date(end) - as.Date(begin)))
    } 
    else{
        nextYear <- as.character(as.integer(temp[1])+1)
        end <- as.Date(paste(nextYear,"01","01",sep="-"))
        return(as.integer(as.Date(end) - as.Date(begin)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the year, or take the current year by default:

```
days.in.month = function(month, year = NULL){

  month = as.integer(month)

  if (is.null(year))
    year = as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y'))

  dt = as.Date(paste(year, month, '01', sep = '-'))
  dates = seq(dt, by = 'month', length = 2)
  as.numeric(difftime(dates[2], dates[1], units = 'days'))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing another one-liner no extra packages needed:

```
NumberOfDays <- function(date) 
return(as.numeric(format(as.Date(paste0(format(date,format="%Y"),formatC(ifelse(format(date,format="%m")=="12",0,as.numeric(format(date,format="%m")))+1,width=2,format="d",flag="0"),"01"),"%Y%m%d")-1,format="%d")))

> NumberOfDays(as.Date("2015-02-14","%Y-%m-%d"))
[1] 28

> system.time(NumberOfDays(as.Date("2015-02-14","%Y-%m-%d")))
    user       system      elapsed
0.0010000000 0.0000000000 0.0009999999
```

You should provide a Date object to this function with the formatting of your own preference.

Answer (score 1):

Hi another way to get the days could be:

```
# Any date
Today <- Sys.Date()
# Get Month and Year
Month <- format(Today,"%m")
Year <- format(Today,"%Y")
# get first date for the next month and then subtract 1
Days <- format(
            as.Date( 
                paste0("01/",(as.numeric(Month)%%12)+1,"/",Year)
                ,"%d/%m/%Y")-1,"%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> Ymd<-"201602"
> lastDate<-format(seq(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s%s",substr(Ymd,1,6),"01"),format="%Y%m%d"),length=2,by="1 month")-1,"%Y%m%d")[2]
> cat(as.integer(lastDate)%%100)
29
# Other Output
> lastDate
[1] "20160229"
> cat(substr(lastDate,7,8))
29
```

Comment: Code only answers don't provide a good solution for the problem. Please try to explain what you did and add information.

Answer (score 0):

This is another alternative solution using zoo's yearmon.
This is a fast utility.

```
require(zoo)
days_in_month <- function(d) {
    rigor_days_in_month <- function(d) {
        get_day <- function(x) as.numeric(format(x,"%d"))
        m <- zoo::as.yearmon(d)
        get_day(as.Date(m, frac = 1))
    }
    mm <- as.numeric(format(d,"%m")) # get_month
    ifelse(mm %in% c(1,3,5,7,8,10,12), 31,
        ifelse(mm != 2, 30, 
           rigor_days_in_month(d)))

}
```

You can unwrap get_day() to make it into a one-liner if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

You just need to use the function `days_in_month()` from `lubridate` package.
Follow a quick example how you can use the function to provide the days in the month.

```
lubridate::days_in_month(as.Date("2018-02-01"))
```

Output:

> Feb   28

For more information about the function: [click here](https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/man/days_in_month.html)

Answer (score -1):

I'm late to the party but this function is much better and supports vectors:

```
month_days <- function(mon) {
  # input as class "Date"
  require(lubridate)
  day(mon) <- 1
  given <- mon
  month(given) <- month(given) + 1
  as.numeric(given - mon)
}
```