# R loop: name objectives by variable

Tags: r, variables, loops

I need to read daily netcdf files every month and give each a name ended with the date

```
library(raster)
year<-2004
startmonth<-1
for(monthd in 31){
    days<-formatC(monthd, width=2, flag="0")
    month<-formatC(startmonth,width=2,flag="0")
    sm=raster(paste(year,month,days,"1.nc",sep=""),varname="sm")
    monthd<monthd+1
}
```

In the end I should have raster objectives named as 
sm01
sm02
.
.
.
sm31

for January. There must be a simple way to do it, I'm just very fresh in coding.

Comment: use `monthd in seq(31)`

Comment: Don't create 31 variables! Use a list structure.

Comment: Or better yet, use `list.files` and then stack the objects into a `rasterstack` using `stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a mean of a set of raster files. Package `raster` has built-in object types for handling situations such as this. It is *much* more efficient to create a rasterStack and use `calc` to find the mean:

```
days<-formatC(1:31, width=2, flag="0")
files <- list( paste("2004" , "01" , days , "1.nc" , sep="" ) )

## First 3 filenames:
files[[1]][1:3]
# [1] "200401011.nc" "200401021.nc" "200401031.nc"

sms <- stack( files )
smMean <- calc( sms , mean , na.rm = TRUE )
```

### Edit based on OP comment

You cannot pass a list of filenames directly to raster. From the manual, it states:

> x:     filename (character), Extent, Raster*, SpatialPixels*, SpatialGrid*, object, 'image', matrix, im, or missing.

Therefore if you *must* have individual raster objects (and I strongly advise against it in this case) then you could use your loop as originally planned, or you could use:

```
smRaster <- lapply( files , raster , varname = "sm" )
```

This will return **one** list object, each element of which is a raster object. This is probably not that useful to you, but you can then access each one using `smRaster[[1]]` , `smRaster[[2]]` etc.

### But use a raster stack if your files have the same extent and resolution!

Reading the files in using `stack` is likely to be more efficient and help you write more readable, shorter code. You can operate on *all* the rasters at once using convenient syntax, e.g. if I wanted to make a new raster that showed the sum of all the other rasters:

```
## First we use our files list to make the rasterStack
smStack <- stack( files , varname = "sm" )

## 'sum' returns a new rasterLayer, each cell is the sum of the corresponding cells in the stack
smSum <- sum( smStack , na.rm = TRUE )

## 'mean' does the same!!
smMean <- mean( smStack , na.rm = TRUE )

## What if we want the mean of only the first 7 days of rasters?
smMean <- mean( smStack[[1:7]] , na.rm = TRUE )

## To see how many rasters in the stack...
nlayers( smStack )

## To make a new object of just the first 7 rasters in the stack
subset( smStack , 1:7 )

## Is roughly equivalent to using the `[[` operator like this to get the first 7 layers in a new object
newRaster <- smStack[[1:7]]

## If you want to access an individual layer..
smStack[[ layernumber/or layername here ]]

## And to get the names:
names( smStack)
```

I would really strongly advise using a stack if you rasters cover the same spatial extent and resolution. It is more efficient, both for R and for your coding to just use a `stack`! I hope I have convinced you! :-)

Comment: I agree stack is a more elegant way doing this. However did you miss a step converting the netcdf files to raster? I found it difficult to do with
    `smRaster<-raster(files)`
Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2271576 I updated the question. In short you can't pass a list of files to `raster`, ***but*** don't use `raster` in this instance use `stack`!! I hope after reading the question I will have convinced you. I *think* it will really aid your work flow. HTH.

Comment: I've already been convinced by using stack, since I thought about stack in the first place, but wanted to avoid adding complexity to the process. I've tried to stack "files" by using `smStack <- stack( files , varname = "sm" )`. However it's giving 10 warnings with the first one "1: In if (x == "" | x == ".") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". Also the smStack only has one layer rather than the desired 31 layers. I've put my soil moisture data here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/47sor6faoi0bsfl/5o6w2g7JVa).

Comment: @EDU I'll have a look into it tomorrow. Have you named your files correctly? If the files are all in the same directory, just use `files <- list.files( "/path/to/directory/" , pattern = ".nc" , full.names=TRUE)`

Comment: I think I've found the reason that stack couldn't read the list. We should use `list.files` rather than `list`, as `list.files` produces a character vector of the names whilst `list` produces a real 'list'. Obviously the `stack` recognizes character vector better. Thank you all very much. I think my question has been fully solve at this stage. Y'all have a pleasant weekend!

Answer (score 0):

First thing: your `for` loop is off, you only iterate over one value, `31`. You need to change it to:

```
for (monthd in 1 : 31) { …
```

Next, to create a variable based on a string, use [`assign`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assign.html):

```
assign(paste('sm', monthd, sep = ''), someValue)
```

Finally, remove the last line of your loop – it’s syntactically wrong and it achieves nothing, once corrected.

However, I strongly advise against using `assign` here. What you want isn’t lots of individual variables, you simply want a *vector*. You can simply create it like this:

```
sm <- vector(length = 31)
# or
sm <- 1 : 31
# or, same as previous
sm <- seq(1, 31)
# or
sm <- rep(someValue, 31)
```

Comment: More robust : for ( monthd in length(n.days) ) where you've determined the number of days in the given month programmatically, e.g. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243088/find-out-the-number-of-days-of-a-month-in-r)

Comment: @c.gutierrez Now you’ve made the same error as OP, you need to replace `length` with `seq` or use `1 : n.days`

Comment: First, thanks for all the help. The reason I want to write 31 rasters is I'll later on do
    `sm_jan<-mean(sm1,sm2...sm31,na.rm=TRUE)`. How may I assign each raster to a list/vector such as sm with values 1 to 31?

Comment: @KonradRudolph my mistake; so becomes : for ( monthd in 1:n.days ) where n.days is returned value from function in above-mentioned post. In the below answer, line 1 becomes days<-formatC(1:n.days, width=2, flag="0" .

Comment: @user2271576 Not sure what you mean by the assignment, but your code becomes simply `sm_jan <- mean(sm, na.rm=TRUE)` and this works *in general*!

Comment: I think the gist of this should be to convince the OP to use a `stack` in this instance. It will be a *lot* more convenient for their use-case!

Comment: @SimonO101 Maybe, I don’t know the `raster` package (don’t work with spatial data) and was just answering the general question about vector / loop usage. I trust your answer is correct though.