# Last Day of Month Function, given Year and Month

Tags: r

I am unable to find what is specifically giving me this error after stepping through the code multiple times. I'm hoping that someone has seen this error before.

Here's what I *think* is relevant to the problem:

```
#### Load packages
library(lubridate)

MONTH <- 1
YEAR <- 2018

# Last day of month
last_day_of_mth <- function(YEAR, MONTH){
  MONTH_BEGIN <- as.POSIXlt(paste0(YEAR, "-", MONTH, "-1"))
  MONTH_END <- MONTH_BEGIN
  day(MONTH_END) <- day(MONTH_BEGIN)
  month(MONTH_END) <- month(MONTH_END) + 1
  day(MONTH_END) <- day(MONTH_END) - 1
  return(as.character(MONTH_END))
}
```

This code loads a bunch of external files via `source()` which do not contain any other packages or other functions. They just query data from the Google Analytics API or they load .csv files, manipulate the data frames, and spit out appropriate output as .csv files.

For some bizarre reason, after running these 10 files via `source()`, it spits out

```
> last_day_of_mth(2018, 1)
[1] "2018-03-02 06:00:00"
```

which is obviously not correct - it should be `2018-01-31`.

Comment: Please remove all the irrelevant source code in this post.  Questions should have *minimal* code.  See [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice that you have used a particular name to your function. I could have used the same function name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two solutions. Both work even if `year` and `month` are vectors instead of the scalars shown here.

**1) as.Date.yearmon** First convert the input to a `"yearmon"` object and then convert that to `"Date"` class using `as.Date` with the `frac=1` argument.

```
library(zoo)

# input    
year <- 2018
month <- 2

ym <- as.yearmon(paste(year, month, sep = "-"))
as.Date(ym, frac = 1)
## [1] [1] "2018-02-28"
```

**2) base** A base solution using `fom` (first of month) from [Find out the number of days of a month in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243088/find-out-the-number-of-days-of-a-month-in-r/6244503#6244503) is the following.  First we convert the year and month to a `"Date"` class object `dat1` for the first of that month and add 32 which is enough days to get to the next month.  Then use `fom` to find the first of that month and subtract 1 to get the last date of the input year/month.

```
fom <- function(x) as.Date(cut(x, "month"))

dat1 <- as.Date(paste(year, month, 1, sep = "-"))
fom(dat1 + 32) - 1
## [1] "2018-02-28"
```

Comment: This is **much** more elegant than what I have. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adapting your own code, and continuing to use `lubridate`:

```
last_day_of_mth <- function(YEAR, MONTH){
  ymd(paste0(YEAR, "-", MONTH, "-1")) %>% 
    ceiling_date(., "month") %>% 
    {.-days(1)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using `Hmisc` library. One can find out maximum number of days in a month after using `year` and `month` with `day=1` to make a date. Then find out max number of days in that month.

Finally use `year`, `month` and `max number of days in month` to make last date in that month.

I have created a function as `lastDayofMonth`

```
library(Hmisc)
lastDayofMonth <- function(year, month){
  as.Date(sprintf("%4d-%2d-%2d", year, month,
           monthDays(as.Date(sprintf("%4d-%2d-%2d", year, month, 1)))
         ))
}

> lastDayofMonth(2018,2)
#[1] "2018-02-28"
> lastDayofMonth(2018,3)
#[1] "2018-03-31"
> lastDayofMonth(2017,3)
#[1] "2017-03-31"
> lastDayofMonth(2000,2)
#[1] "2000-02-29"
```