# Dplyr:: filter function working selectively

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter a dataset by each month but the 2nd code line does not execute. The 1st and 3rd work fine. The 2nd gives me this error:

> Error in `filter()`:
> ! Problem while computing `..1 = CloseDate >= "2022-02-01" & CloseDate <= "2022-02-31"`.
> Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
> ! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
>
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. dplyr::filter(...)
> 2. lubridate (local) `<=.POSIXt`(CloseDate, "2022-02-31")
> 3. base::as.POSIXct.default(e2)
> 4. base::as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...)
> 5. base::stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")

The Code:

```
ACntyJan2022 <- filter(AlamedaCnty, CloseDate >= "2022-01-01" & 
 CloseDate <= "2022-01-31")

ACntyMeanSPJan2022 \<- mean(ACntyJan2022$SP)

ACntyFeb2022 <- filter(AlamedaCnty, CloseDate >= "2022-02-01" & 
 CloseDate <= "2022-02-31")
ACntyMeanSPFeb2022 <- mean(ACntyFeb2022$SP)

ACntyMrch2022 <- filter(AlamedaCnty, CloseDate >= as.POSIXct("2022-03-01") & 
 CloseDate <= as.POSIXct("2022-03-31"))

ACntyMeanSPMrch2022 <- mean(ACntyMrch2022$SP)
```

I am losing my head over trying to figure out what the issue is. Please help me.

Comment: Please share your data using dput directly in your question. See here: stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput

Comment: What would you like February 31 to mean? Is it before or after March 1? Date comparisons are only possible using  dates that can exist.

Comment: JonSpring hit it on the head: there is no way to make a timestamp-like object (`POSIXt` in R) that is not a legal date/time. Just like `"2022-03-01 27:11:29"` is not possible, neither is `*-02-31`. If you really have to use the last day of Feb and want to do it programmatically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871303/3358272) may be of use, as it returns the last day of a given month.