# Given a date range how to expand to the number of days per month in that range?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

**Case:**
Given are a dataframe `df` with (among others) a `startDate` and an `endDate` column. My goal is to "transform" `df` to a new dataframe `df_res` that contains one row for every month occuring in the interval `(startDate, endDate)`, with additional columns `year`, `month` and `numberOfDaysInMonth`, all of type int.

**Example:**
*Input:* `df`

```
  id    startDate     endDate  someOtherCol
   1   2017-09-23  2018-02-01          val1
   2   2018-01-01  2018-03-31          val2
 ...          ...         ...           ...
```

*Desired output:* `df_res`

```
  id  year  month  numberOfDaysInMonth  someOtherCol
   1  2017      9                    8          val1
   1  2017     10                   31          val1
   1  2017     11                   30          val1
   1  2017     12                   31          val1
   1  2018      1                   31          val1
   1  2018      2                    1          val1
   2  2018      1                   31          val2
   2  2018      2                   28          val2
   2  2018      3                   31          val2
 ...   ...    ...                  ...           ...
```

**Background:**
I am relatively new to R but aware of the great `dplyr`and `lubridate` packages. I just did not manage to achieve the above in a neat way, even when using those packages. The closest I got was this: [Expand rows by date range using start and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803361/expand-rows-by-date-range-using-start-and-end-date), but that does not yield the number of days per month contained in the range.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]! Do not use images to present your data, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example !

Comment: `seq.Date` can go by `month`, see `?seq.Date`.

Comment: Besides that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243088/find-out-the-number-of-days-of-a-month-in-r

Comment: Hello @jogo, thank you for your response. I have reformatted the dataframes. Is it okay like this?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico. I checked both. I understand how these operate individualy, but do not get how to apply them to get from `df` to `df_res`. Also, the latter finds the number of days in a given month, but I am looking for the number of days in a month that are contained in the interval `(startDate, endDate)` (see example). Do you know how to do just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
# example data
df = read.table(text = "
id    startDate     endDate  someOtherCol
1   2017-09-23  2018-02-01          val1
2   2018-01-01  2018-03-31          val2
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(startDate, endDate), ymd) %>%                  # update to date columns (if needed)
  group_by(id) %>%                                              # for each id
  mutate(d = list(seq(startDate, endDate, by="1 day"))) %>%     # create a sequence of dates (as a list)
  unnest() %>%                                                  # unnest data
  group_by(id, year=year(d), month=month(d), someOtherCol) %>%  # group by those variables (while getting year and month of each date in the sequence)
  summarise(numberOfDaysInMonth = n()) %>%                      # count days
  ungroup()                                                     # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#      id  year month someOtherCol numberOfDaysInMonth
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                      <int>
# 1     1  2017     9 val1                           8
# 2     1  2017    10 val1                          31
# 3     1  2017    11 val1                          30
# 4     1  2017    12 val1                          31
# 5     1  2018     1 val1                          31
# 6     1  2018     2 val1                           1
# 7     2  2018     1 val2                          31
# 8     2  2018     2 val2                          28
# 9     2  2018     3 val2                          31
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot, @AntoniosK.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind a `data.table` solution, you can create a sequence of consecutive dates between startDate and endDate before you aggregate by id, someOtherCol, year and month as follows:

```
dat[, .(Dates=seq(startDate, endDate, by="1 day")), by=.(id, someOtherCol)][,
    .N, by=.(id, someOtherCol, year(Dates), month(Dates))]
```

output:

```
   id someOtherCol year month  N
1:  1         val1 2017     9  8
2:  1         val1 2017    10 31
3:  1         val1 2017    11 30
4:  1         val1 2017    12 31
5:  1         val1 2018     1 31
6:  1         val1 2018     2  1
7:  2         val2 2018     1 31
8:  2         val2 2018     2 28
9:  2         val2 2018     3 31
```

data:

```
library(data.table)    
dat <- fread("id    startDate     endDate  someOtherCol
1   2017-09-23  2018-02-01          val1
2   2018-01-01  2018-03-31          val2")
datecols <- c("startDate", "endDate")
dat[, (datecols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols=datecols]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @chinsoon12. Although this works fine, I prefer the `tidyverse` solution as it is easier - at least to me - to follow its logic. The computation time constraint in my application will probably not be binding, so I did not compare this method with @AntoniosK 's proposal on computational performance.