# Get the number of days from the date column

Tags: r

I have column - Month, and there are few months, I need to find out the number of day in that month.

I need to find the number of days in a month considering the leap year and that the month can go to June 2019, or current month. The logic should be applied on the column.

```
MONTH           no_of_days
Jan,2017
Feb,2017
Mar,2017
Apr,2017
May,2017
Jun,2017
Jul,2017
Aug,2017
Sep,2017
Oct,2017
Nov,2017
Dec,2017
```

structure(list(MONTH = structure(c(9L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 
11L, 3L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 
4L, 24L, 22L, 20L, 6L), .Label = c("Apr,2017", "Apr,2018", "Aug,2017", 
"Aug,2018", "Dec,2017", "Dec,2018", "Feb,2017", "Feb,2018", "Jan,2017", 
"Jan,2018", "Jul,2017", "Jul,2018", "Jun,2017", "Jun,2018", "Mar,2017", 
"Mar,2018", "May,2017", "May,2018", "Nov,2017", "Nov,2018", "Oct,2017", 
"Oct,2018", "Sep,2017", "Sep,2018"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))

Comment: Is the problem finding out how many days are in a month or is it the coding?

Comment: need to find the number of days in a month how can we find out, considering the leap year and the month can go to June 2019 ,, or current month, logic should be applied on the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first get the column `MONTH` to `Date` and then use any of the function shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243088/find-out-the-number-of-days-of-a-month-in-r) to get number of days in a month.

```
as.Date(paste0(1, df$MONTH), "%d%b,%Y")
#[1] "2017-01-01" "2017-02-01" "2017-03-01" "2017-04-01" "2017-05-01" "2017-06-01" 
#    "2017-07-01" "2017-08-01" "2017-09-01" "2017-10-01" "2017-11-01" "2017-12-01"

Hmisc::monthDays(as.Date(paste0(1, df$MONTH), "%d%b,%Y"))
#[1] 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(MONTH = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr,2017", "Aug,2017", "Dec,2017", 
"Feb,2017", "Jan,2017", "Jul,2017", "Jun,2017", "Mar,2017", "May,2017", 
"Nov,2017", "Oct,2017", "Sep,2017"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: betterDates <- as.Date(input$MONTH, format = "%B %d %y ") - but it helped, getting all NA's , please suggest

Comment: @Robbystar Please check the answer. add `1` first since you don't have date component, also use the correct format as shown. Do `betterDates <- as.Date(paste0(1, input$MONTH), format = "%d%b %Y ")`

Comment: tried it still gettig all NA's

Comment: class(input$MONTH) - is factor

Comment: do you really have what you have shown here then? I have updated my post with the data I am using. Can you check how is it different from the data you have? If it is different please do `dput(input)` and update the post.

Comment: i am talking about the first step, as it is Jan, 2017, so i have to convert it into date right, somewhat 01/2017 kind of, so im stuck here

Comment: that is what I am doing in first step. You have got dates like `Jan,2017` right? Do `as.Date(paste0(1, "Jan,2017"), "%d%b,%Y")` you get a date. Now extend this to all the values in your column. `as.Date(paste0(1, input$MONTH), "%d%b,%Y")`

Comment: its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The package `lubridate` has a function called `days_in_month()`. So you can first convert the `MONTH` column into dates and then use `days_in_month`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

df <- structure(list(MONTH = structure(c(9L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 11L, 3L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 4L, 24L, 22L, 20L, 6L), .Label = c("Apr,2017", "Apr,2018", "Aug,2017", "Aug,2018", "Dec,2017", "Dec,2018", "Feb,2017", "Feb,2018", "Jan,2017", "Jan,2018", "Jul,2017", "Jul,2018", "Jun,2017", "Jun,2018", "Mar,2017", "Mar,2018", "May,2017", "May,2018", "Nov,2017", "Nov,2018", "Oct,2017", "Oct,2018", "Sep,2017", "Sep,2018"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

df$no_of_days <- days_in_month(as.Date(as.yearmon(df$MONTH, "%b,%Y")))
```

Comment: You haven't provided a working answer.

Comment: Why not? The OP asked "I need to find the number of days in a month considering the leap year and that the month can go to June 2019, or current month. The logic should be applied on the column." which I believe I answered.

Comment: what happens if you punch `df$no_of_days <- days_in_month(df$MONTH)` into R? What if the asker doesn't know how to convert to a date format? Your answer is incomplete and doesn't work.

Comment: With that logic, you also would need to add then he first needs to install lubridate for your example to be a working one?

Comment: If it helps, sure.

Comment: @akrun, many thanks, I've made the edits.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrangle your `MONTH` column into a `date` object, then you can use `lubridate::days_in_month()`:

```
if (!require(lubridate)) install.packages('lubridate')
if (!require(dplyr)) install.packages('dplyr')

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(MONTH = paste("01", MONTH, sep = ",") %>% dmy(),
         no_of_days = days_in_month(MONTH))

# A tibble: 12 x 2
   MONTH      no_of_days
   <date>          <int>
 1 2017-01-01         31
 2 2017-02-01         28
 3 2017-03-01         31
 4 2017-04-01         30
 5 2017-05-01         31
 6 2017-06-01         30
 7 2017-07-01         31
 8 2017-08-01         31
 9 2017-09-01         30
10 2017-10-01         31
11 2017-11-01         30
12 2017-12-01         31
```

Comment: betterDates <- as.Date(input$MONTH, format = "%B %d %y ")

Comment: but getting all NA's